# does procrob face_recognition package work with the kinect camera? I am using openni drivers to run at the moment

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a facial recognition package on ros hydro for a project. I intend to use procrob face_detection but I a, concerned whether it will work with the kinect camera . Currently I am using openni_launch to access the camera and some other functionalities , also it would be very helful if someone can tell me what services I might be able to use in conjunction with the openni library

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200123/does-procrob-face_recognition-package-work-with-the-kinect-camera?-i-am-using-openni-drivers-to-run-at-the-moment/) by [daniyal_336](https://answers.ros.org/users/21249/daniyal_336/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe it should work if you subscribe the face recognition package to the rgb/image_raw from Kinect, but please notice that the ProCRob face recognition only considers 2D images and does not use the depth information.

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0